# How to react differently to custom events, depending on the calling class?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, events, delegates

I'm lost in how to design the best class architecture for my problem. I use a CardReader object, which throws the following events:

```
// CardReader has read a card
public event CardReader.CardReadHandler CardRead;

// CardReader has a log message which can be processed
public event CardReader.LoggingHandler CardReaderLogging;

// A new hardware is connected to the computer
public event CardReader.ConnectHandler ReaderConnect;
```

In my WPF application, I would like to react differently on these events. For example:

- In a MainWindow, the CardRead event must lead to some kind of processing (card ID -> backend etc.)
- In a ConfigurationWindow, the CardRead event only leads to a "Success"-Message or something

I hesitate to process those events in the window classes, it feels as if it belongs to an own processing class or something. Currently, I wrote a wrapper class, which takes for example the MainWindow and is then able to execute MainWindow methods (because it keeps a private reference to the calling MainWindow):

```
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
this.cardReader = new CardReader(this);
}
```

If I continue this thought, this would lead to separate CardReader wrapper classes, each taking a different kind of window:

```
public ConfigurationWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();
this.cardReader = new CardReader(this);
}
```

Do you have a suggestion here?

Comment: What determines which window is actually being shown? Do you have a controller class somewhere managing that? What code you _want_ to be responsible for the different responses to the events? The answer could be as simple as subscribing different handlers depending on which window is shown, but without more context it's hard to know. I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with the approach you're apparently already using (different wrapper classes, depending on window).

Comment: The user defines, what windows are being shown (primarily by clicking on menu items). I decided to implement those 3 handler methods in the calling classes. This leads to different implementations in different places, but it would be the same as if I created different handler classes for each window. Thanks for your response, brought me back on track!